# Why can't I connect to an apple _apple-midi._udp. NetService using NSNetService?

Tags: cocoa, core-audio, bonjour, nsnetservice, coremidi

I am receiving an error when opening an inputstream on an apple published bonjour netservice, _apple-midi._udp. I get the following error:
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused" UserInfo=0x100358780 {}.

Does Apple frown on people trying to access a midi stream this way? I am trying to create a discoverable list of midi network streams that a client can select from. I am trying to remove the Audio Midi Setup application from the equation when connecting via MacOSX.

Thanks,

Patrick

Comment: I have a similar problem

Comment: Well I suspect that it can't be accessed. Its probably internal to Apple. What I have decided to do is rebroadcast the data, as sync doesn't need to be sample accurate (not that the _apple-mdi._udp would be anything close to sample of quarter-frame accurate).